# rails 3 assets - permission issue after changing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

After changing my logo, i got the following error:

Error compiling asset header_logo_v2.png:
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - (path to tmp/cache/assets/CB0/E00/sprockets%2F1d4414e34df7725375b214c95386d7aa)

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add write access for temp/cache/assets folder to user which runs rails application or to its group